# Do any desktop environments (preferably KDE) support separate X screens?

Tags: rhel, xorg, kde, nvidia, window-manager

I am looking to run KDE plasma 5 on multiple X Screens (:0.0, :0.1, :0.2, etc). My current set up is 2 displays on 2 separate X screens with nvidia drivers, but when plasma starts only :0.0 actually has plasma/kwin running on it. :0.1 is a black screen, with an X for a cursor. I've been successful in running this set up on KDE4 plasma (on RHEL7) and am hoping to continue to do so on Plasma 5 (in RHEL 8). I am able to manually set DISPLAY in bash to :0.1 and launch an X window such as xterm to :0.1, however interacting with that window does not work correctly.

There are two main reasons why I would like to run my display set up like this. First and foremost, is the ability to switch virtual desktops on a per display basis. Secondly, the ability to remotely launch X windows to specific displays.

In the past I have gotten this display set up working on RHEL 5 running KDE, RHEL 6 running Gnome2, and then again on RHEL 7 running KDE4. I'm now on RHEL 8 attempting to use KDE 5 Plasma, but have not been successful and have been unable to find any good resources relating to a multi head set up on separate X displays.

On KDE4 for each screen that is set up, there is a qdbus object for each screen for plasma-desktop and for kwin.

Here is what the qdbus objects look like from a successful set up on RHEL7 running KDE4

```
# qdbus | grep plasma-desktop
org.kde.plasma-desktop
org.kde.plasma-desktop-screen-1
org.kde.plasma-desktop-screen-2
org.kde.plasma-desktop-screen-3
```

```
# qdbus | grep kwin
org.kde.kwin
org.kde.kwin-screen-1
org.kde.kwin-screen-2
org.kde.kwin-screen-3
```

I'm hoping that it is possible to get something similar set up in Plasma KDE 5.

Here is my xorg.conf file for good measure:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 460.67

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics LG Ultra HD"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 135.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 61.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung C24FG70"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 168.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 144.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    BusID          "PCI:8:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    BusID          "PCI:8:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-5"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-2: 1920x1080 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-3"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you should be able to set X up like this using the Nvidia tools. Basically it's about removing xinerama. You'll need to login twice and run two desktop managers - not all of them can cope with that concept though; you might have to revert to (much) older window manager tools

Comment: The X set up above is working as intended. I get a :0.0 display and a :0.1 display. It's just I've been unable to get a desktop environment up on :0.1. Display :0.0 is a fully functioning desktop environment and Display :0.1 is a black screen and when I move the cursor into it, it is just an X. I've tried using mate, kde 5 plasma, and gnome so far. Do you have any suggestion of another one to try?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. The "X" cursor means that X is running on that screen but there's neither window manager nor desktop manager looking after it. (I'm surprised it's a black background and not the default hatched one.) Can you run a Desktop Manager with `DISPLAY=:0.1`, or doesn't it care?

Comment: I think that I have only attempted to run a Window Manager on the second display. For example, in the command line I will `export DISPLAY=:0.1` and then run `kwin`. What happens is that DBUS recognizes that another window manager is already running and kills the attempt to run a second one. I have not tried running a Desktop Manager on the second display. It's unclear to me how to do that because I feel like the ones that I mentioned before (plasma 5, gnome, mate) all launch their desktop manager as a part of launching X as well. I'm happy to give it a shot if you can tell mehow.

Comment: I wondered if dbus would get in the way. Two different user accounts? I'm out of ideas, sorry

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll give two user accounts a try. I've also considered seeing if some sort of multi seat set up would work and then maybe going from there. Either way thanks for the ideas!

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, you may want to ask the KDE folks about it. https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=289 seems like a reasonable place to start.

Comment: I posted in the kwin forum a few weeks back, but I could try the plasma forum as well. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Natolio did you ever find a way to do this? I'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: @dieortin unfortunately not. The more I looked into it, the less feasible it became. At one point I was able to get a very odd configuration set up where I had two window managers running, one on each X screen, but that was not very useful. There is a desktop environment called enlightenment that DOES support separate X screens, but it was not my cup of tea. Ultimately, I just bit the bullet and switched to using plasma 5 without separate X screens. Sorry I don't have a good answer for you, but happy to answer any other questions you have...I spent a long time trying on this one.